# C - All arrays are true printf how would I do that?

Tags: arrays

I want to print something like no errors occurred if there were no problems with  all the array numbers the loop, if that makes sense, how would i do that? Thanks

```
for(i = 0;i<hour;i++){
    if(volt[i] > f || volt[i] <af){
        printf("there was an error at hour: %d  with the voltage: %.1f\n",i+1, volt[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a variable that is set for when there is an error, and after the loop, if not set, print out no errors.

```
int have_error = 0;

for(i = 0;i<hour;i++){
    if(volt[i] > f || volt[i] <af){
        printf("there was an error at hour: %d  with the voltage: %.1f\n",i+1, volt[i]);
        have_error = 1;
    }
}
if(have_error == 0) printf("No errors\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not hot on C but:

Declare a boolean or int variable outside the loop called something like numbersOK. Set its inital value to true or 1.  In your "if" branch (i.e. where you've detected there was an invalid number) set it to false or 0.

After the end of the loop you can test numbersOK and display a message accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag. Let's name an integer variable as flag. Before the for loop flag is gonna be down (value equals to zero). If the if condition is met then the flag is gonna be set to 1 (flag is up). So in the end, after the for loop has ended you can check the value of the flag. If it is down then no errors occurred and you can print the no errors message.

Also i would form the if statement to something like that:

```
if( (volt[i] > f) || (volt[i] <af) )
```

just to be sure it will be compiled correctly.